# Cuda Error Message : F ./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_launch_config.h:127] Check failed: work_element_count > 0 (0 vs. 0)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a [mask rcnn model](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) using Keras on my own dataset on a p2.xlarge EC2 aws instance.

When I launch the training, after a few steps of training:

```
Epoch 1/1    2/1000 [..............................] - ETA: 4:27:49 - loss: 5.1578 - rpn_class_loss: 0.0937 - rpn_bbox_loss: 0.6471 - mrcnn_class_loss: 2.6594 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 1.1266 - mrcnn_mask_loss:
0.6311
```

I get this error message:

```
2018-05-02 13:44:56.193439: F ./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_launch_config.h:127] Check failed: work_element_count > 0 (0 vs. 0)
```

My images are relatively small (~100Kb), few images in my dataset (~150).

The config I am using is as follow:

```
class CustomConfig(Config):
    """Configuration for training on the custom dataset.
    Derives from the base Config class
    """
    # Give the configuration a recognizable name
    NAME = "blabla"

    # We use a GPU with 12GB memory, which can fit two images.
    # Adjust down if you use a smaller GPU.
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 2

    # Number of classes (including background)
    NUM_CLASSES = 11
```

Any suggestion ? Thanks !

Comment: I am facing the same problem with tensorflow 1.12 on windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded my tensorflow-gpu package to 1.7.0 and it worked

Comment: If i'm not wrong the github repo clearly asks for 1.5 version of tensorflow